# Fourier transform in Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: fourier-transform, definition, maxwell-equations, greens-functions, klein-gordon-equation

I'm Solving (or at least trying to solve) 4 Klein Gordon equation with sources (Maxwell equations) with the Green function method, therefore I have

$$
\Box G(x,x')= \delta^4(x-x')
\tag{1}$$

Where $G$ is the green function and the arguments of the functions are 4-vectors.

To Find the Green function we use the Fourier transform, and here there is my problem, which is mainly a terminology problem. We write

$$
G(x-x') = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d^4k \tilde{G}(k) e^{-ik \cdot (x-x')}
\tag{2}$$

Now to my definition of Fourier Transform which is
$$
(F f)(x)= \tilde{f}(x)= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2}} \int \,\tilde{f}(k) e^{-ix \cdot k} d^nk
\tag{3}$$

I have that $G$ is the Fourier transform of $\tilde{G}$, apart from a factor $(2\pi)^{1/2}$ missing in equation $(2)$ which i cannot explain.

Is my view right? Both my book and my notes says that $\tilde{G}$ is the Fourier transform of $G$ while in my opinion $\tilde{G}$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $G$.

I mean in $(2)$ I'm Fourier transforming  the inverse Fourier transform of $G$ and that's why I obtain $G$, which is by means of the inversion equation:
$$
f=(F(\overline{F} f) 
\tag{4}$$

Where $\overline{F} f$ is the inverse Fourier Transform.

I'm probably missing something and the answer may be banal, but, if I am, where am I wrong? And why is there a missing factor of $(2\pi)^{1/2}$ ?

Hoping that someone enlighten me, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @knzhou I'm sorry, I checked before posting the answer but didn't find that. I'll read it as soon as I can, and if I notice it is a duplicate and it answer my question what should I do? Delete this question?